# Loading a file path from a text file and inputting it as the source for a video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, video

I have been trying my hardest to not have to ask this here. But, alas... I cannot get the thing to work. I am a python programmer but have the briefest of requirements to output something in HTML. So I dont have time to dig into JQuery properly and understand the syntax, I have been trying to "bodge" it... but alas... no joy!

I have written a maltego transform in python that creates a concatonated path (source + entity name) and outputs that as a text file. I then pass that entity to a web browser which redirects the user to the video display page. I then need to import that text file using JQuery, slot the path from that text file into a variable and then drop that variable into the src for a video.

Basic HTML, its sole purpose is to enable the user to click full screen on the video at the end of a series of transforms which finds videos associated with the entity name. Nothing fancy.

The file that contains the path is called "path.txt".

```
    <HTML>
<HEAD>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <body>

    <video id="video1" width="520" height="440" src="" type="video/mp4" controls>
      <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

<script>

$('#video1').load("path.txt", function(response) {
  var path = response;

  $("#video1").attr("src", path);

alert(path);
});

</script>

  </body>

</body>
</HTML>
```

This is probably something that I am going to want to kick myself in the shin over... but if someone could clear this up for me (and explain!) it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is your video locally stored or on the internet? the path should be something like http: //www.domain.com/folder/video.mp4 in quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, your js syntax is incorrect. You have other errors in your html that should be noted however. The `center` tag is deprecated: use margin (auto) instead. Also, i don't think the source requires an id. I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/zso4ag55/) (or you can run the snippet). Obviously you will have to create a path.txt and load it in order for the function to work

```js
function load_file() {

  $("#logList").load("path.txt", function(response) {
    var path = response;

    $("#video1").attr("src", path);
    alert("test " + path);


  });
}
```

```css
video {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <input type="button" value="Load" onclick="load_file()" />


  <video id="video1" width="520" height="440" src="" type="video/mp4" controls>
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
  </video>


</body>
```

Comment: just an addendum - ensure you have your doctype set correctly also - it should be <!doctype html>

Comment: Ive amended the code above, can you take a look at where I am. Ive got it outputting the variable in an alert... its just not passing it to the SRC!

Comment: Just saw msg now will have a look

Comment: What are you getting in the alert as the path?

Comment: it looks like you have you have 2 srcs actually, it may be passing successfully to the first one, but seeing that the source src="" is empty and then not playing it. Perhaps remove the source src line and it will work. like this : https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/L12h36g0/ . Ideally, video code would look like this https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/0yrn9owh/ - cross browser compatible - but mp4 should do.

Comment: Ill take a look tomorrow. Everything is local, so file type wont matter. Its just strange that it doesnt like the full path being passed to the src... the alert returned the full path, but as soon as the path was amended and only included the file name in the same directory as the executing script, it worked fine...!

Comment: @Wete_Pilliams well it needs to be at least on a server. it won't read from the desktop, for instance. if the path isn't like i said, it's not gonna work. It will work once hosted.

Comment: @Wete_Pilliams i see you have enough rep now to upvote? You get a badge for your first one..  go one you know you want to! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your JS code syntax is incorrect. You have several mis-matched brackets and braces. Also, the usage of the `response` needs to all occur within the `load()` callback handler as the AJAX request is asynchronous. Try this:

```
function load_file() {
    $("#logList").load("path.txt", function(response) { 
        var path = response.trim();
        $("#video1").attr("src", path);
    });
}
```

Comment: Ive amended the code above, can you take a look at where I am. Ive got it outputting the variable in an alert... its just not passing it to the SRC!

Comment: You missed the `trim()`

Comment: It wasnt actually that... for some reason it doesnt like the pathname...

If I remove the path name and just place the video in the root directory of the html it works fine! Strange. Any reason why this would be?